# Why are special characters not drawn properly?

Tags: fonts, pdfbox

I use pdfBox to easily create some pdfs. But I got in trouble when I use special
characters like ş ı o ü ö etc.

Example 1: when I use **PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;**
[image: Example 1]

Example 2: when I use **PDFont font = PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(document,...**
[image]

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;



import org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.COSVisitorException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.edit.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;

public class PDFExample {

PDFExample() {} //constructor

public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException, COSVisitorException {
    // Create a document and add a page to it
    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = new PDPage();
    document.addPage( page );

    // Create a new font object selecting one of the PDF base fonts
    PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;

    // Start a new content stream which will "hold" the to be created content
    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);

    // Define a text content stream using the selected font, moving the cursor and drawing the text "Hello World"
    contentStream.beginText();
    contentStream.setFont( font, 12 );
    contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount( 100, 700 );
    contentStream.drawString("ş ı ç o ü ö "); // <---- non us characters
    contentStream.endText();

    // Make sure that the content stream is closed:
    contentStream.close();

    // Save the results and ensure that the document is properly closed:
    document.save( "test.pdf");
    document.close();
}

}
```

I even tried to embed another truetype font such as Gentium, unfortunately my text were drawn with some rendering failures.

Is it a bug? How can solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved. Download latest version of [fontbox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/downloads.cgi). Load your unicode font and print it.

```
InputStream istream =getClass().getResourceAsStream("/font/your_font.ttf");
//byte[] arialNorm = PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(document, istream);

PDFont font = PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(document,istream);
//PDFont font = PDType1Font.COURIER;
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
contentStream.beginText();
contentStream.setFont(font, 18);
contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(100, 700);
contentStream.drawString("unicode_value");
contentStream.endText();
```